# Sharing a link with fbjs on facebook

Tags: facebook, share, fbjs

I've read through the web after being given advice to use the jbjs SDK to share a link on facebook with specified image, title, link ...

Maybe someone experienced can tell me how to do that or at least, where I can find something specific on my sharing idea ... because I'm a newbe on the fbjs ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FBJS has been deprecated by Facebook. Look at the new javascript sdk:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

To share links you use the FB.ui method.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

Consider you need user input for this, it's just the way it works.

Comment: thx, does user input mean, that when before call the fb.ui the hole call stack has to be triggered bei a user event? Or is this a specific user input working with a fb button ???

Comment: User input means you open a dialog for the user and the user needs to click "Publish" or whatever the button says (I don't recall)

Comment: Yes. My point was that you can't post automaticaly, without showing the user a dialog. Sorry if I wasn't clear.